# Tora: No connection provider

Tags: mysql

I install tora on ubuntu 12.04. When I try to open, I'm unable to connect mysql database. 
Tora is not showing option for mysql.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok I've found it.
`sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-mysql` for using mysql
`sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-psql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-sql-odbc libqt4-sql-tds` for obtaining other options also.

Comment: what should I do for Oracle 10.2.0.3?

Comment: Sorry @Dinesh, no suggestion from me as Oracle is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Oracle missing...